# Edge pruning in graph

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

Im just starting out with my python - graphs adventure and I have just encountered a conceptional problem. So, my data is some activities which have happend over time - activity, timestamp and some additional data. I want to create graph that shows consecutive steps, so I join data on time condition. My ideal graph whould show that A->B->C->D, but because A is always initial step i get A->B (which is ok) and obsolete A->C, A->D. So my questions is do you know any smart way to prune those edges leaving only important ones? I was thinking about maybe some function in networkx? Please help.

Comment: First sort the activities by time.  Then construct graph with links ONLY between successive activities.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.